# Use of undetermined coefficients issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given the problem
$$y'' + 4y' = t$$
and asked to solve for y. I compute the general solution (using the characteristic equation) to be 
$$c_1 + c_2e^{-4t}\ ,$$
which I am pretty sure is correct.

Next I compute the particular solution to be 
$$At + B\ ,$$
as $t$ is a polynomial of degree one. This leaves me with
$$0 + 4A = t$$
by substitution back into the initial equation, as $(At + B)'' = 0$ and $(At + B)' = A$. I rearrange and find that
$$A = t/4\ ,$$
which doesn't seem like the right answer, and leaves me no apparent way to solve for $B$.

I'm not sure whether I did this wrong or just don't know the next step, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that your homogeneous solution
$$c_1+c_2e^{-4t}$$
and your attempt at a particular solution
$$y_p=At+B$$
have a term in common, namely the constant.  So you should multiply by $t$ and try
$$y_p=At^2+Bt$$
instead.

Comment: And suddenly it makes sense. Blind spot, I guess.

Comment: But it obviously doesn't make sense to some people - I wonder why the downvote?